# PowerApps customize form - unable to submit data to Sharepoint list: There was a problem saving your changes. Data source may be invalid

Tags: powerapps

I am a no voice in PowerApps and have been developing a custom form from the SharePoint list. I am unable to save the form data from SharePoint list through Powerapp form, I am able to save data from Powerapp tool to SharePoint list though.

I have tried refreshing the SP list, form by removing the powerapp form option in Form settings and adding back the powerapp form multiple times. Still no luck! Also verified if the list had any mandatory columns to be filled, but none.

[On click of save/submit error message is notified - Data Source may be invalid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YeVxY.png)

Since I am unable to debug the Powerapp form, I do not understand the exact issue. Please help me with this. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

as you have already noticed, debugging an embedded SharePoint form app can be difficult. One thing you can do is to either run Fiddler or open the browser Developer Tools to see the network traffic when you try to save the form data. If you see a network request being made to SharePoint (might be a POST call to *.azure-apim.net/invoke), then you can check the response to see what error is being returned by SharePoint. If you do not see a call going out to SharePoint, then validation on PowerApps' end may be failing and blocking the request from going out to SharePoint.

Historically, I have seen issues with SharePoint form apps when users try to customize the form by editing/adding fields in the form control. If you've made changes that you think may have caused the form to stop working, I would consider deleting the custom form and starting over. You can do this following the steps at:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/customize-list-form#use-the-default-form

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I some how managed to identify the cause and resolved the issue! It was a hyperlink column which was returning picture as format. PowerApps does not support picture format for hyperlinks and had to change it to hyperlink format. That solved the issue.